# Save coordinates of box on HTML5 canvas through form submission

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I'm designing a web front-end for a service that analyzes videos. In order to allow users to specify a region of interest in the videos they upload, I'm extract the first frame and presenting it as a PNG in an HTML5 canvas.

```
<!-- HTML here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas = document.getElementById('theCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = document.getElementById('image').value;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
</script>
<input type="hidden" id="image" value="{PHP inserts path to image here}" />
```

There's javascript in the background that I'm using to allow users to draw a box on the image. The problem I'm having is this: **how do I save the coordinates of the box that's drawn?** Is it possible to do over a standard POST? Or is there javascript involved in that, too?

(e.g. the [x,y] coordinates of the top-left corner of the box, plus the width and height)

Comment: You really should only draw the image inside `img.onload`, currently you're drawing when the image might not be (fully) loaded yet.

Comment: Sorry, I'm somewhat of a JS noob...would you mind expounding on that point with an example?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading but do you currently already have any box selecting code?

Comment: Here magsol, [Using Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images).

Comment: @pimvdb: I left that part out; there's a canvas tag above the code chunk I wrote, plus a decently large javascript file that handles the box-drawing. It works fine, so I didn't feel all that code needed to be included, but I can post it if that would help.

Comment: @Andrew: That's excellent, thanks for the link regarding onload().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since only your JS code is responsible for the box coordinates, it has to let the browser know the coordinates.

Do you have a submission process already? It could be implemented through an HTML <form> or completely in JS (XMLHttpRequest, also often called 'ajax', e.g. in jquery).

If you had AJAX-based submission, you probably wouldn't ask this question, so I'm assuming you have an HTML <form>. To submit the box coordinates you'll need to add a few inputs in the form:

```
<!-- Instead of this you have a canvas with the box-selecting JS code.
     When the user makes a selection, code similar to setCoords should
     execute with the actual coordinates the user selected. -->
<input type="button" value="Set coordinates" onclick="setCoords(0,0,0,0)">

<form action="...">
  <input id="x" name="x" type="hidden">
  <input id="y" name="y" type="hidden">
  <input id="w" name="w" type="hidden">
  <input id="h" name="h" type="hidden">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<script>
  function setCoords(x,y,w,h) {
    document.getElementById("x").value = x;
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This was the approach that was coalescing in my own mind; thanks for making it concrete! Works like a charm.